# Magento's getMethods function, how does it work?

Tags: php, magento, payment-processing

There's a function in Magento called getMethods(). I'm wondering what this particular line means?

```
Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL
```

This is the context of that line:

```
public function getMethods()
    {
        $methods = $this->getData('methods');
        if ($methods === null) {
            $quote = $this->getQuote();
            $store = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;
            $methods = array();
            foreach ($this->helper('payment')->getStoreMethods($store, $quote) as $method) {
                if ($this->_canUseMethod($method) && $method->isApplicableToQuote(
                    $quote,
                    Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL
                )) {
                    $this->_assignMethod($method);
                    $methods[] = $method;
                }
            }
            $this->setData('methods', $methods);
        }
        return $methods;
    }
```

Comment: look for the `CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL` method in the class file

Answer (score 0):

Here `CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL` is a constant and `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL` will get the value of constant `CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL` defined in class `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`

You can find this class at below path

> your_magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php